# Page Redirects but doesn't respond 301 code - React Router

Tags: reactjs, redirect, react-router

I'm using react-router in my ReactJS application where I'm using following command to redirect page.

```
this.context.router.replace(generateProductURL(oProduct));
```

This redirects the page properly but with `200 OK` code. I want 301 incase of redirection. Any help??

Here is my server code:

```
match({ history, routes: getRoutes(store), location: req.originalUrl }, (error, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {
    if (redirectLocation) {
      res.redirect(redirectLocation.pathname + redirectLocation.search);
    } else if (error) {
      console.error('ROUTER ERROR:', pretty.render(error));
      res.status(500);
      hydrateOnClient();
    } else if (renderProps) {
      loadOnServer({...renderProps, store, helpers: {client}}).then(() => {
        const component = (
          <Provider store={store} key="provider">
            <ReduxAsyncConnect {...renderProps} />
          </Provider>
        );

        const is404 = renderProps.routes.find(r => r.status === 404) !== undefined;
        if (is404) {
          res.status(404);
        } else {
          res.status(200);
        }

        global.navigator = {userAgent: req.headers['user-agent']};

        res.send('<!doctype html>\n' +
          ReactDOM.renderToString(<Html assets={webpackIsomorphicTools.assets()} component={component} store={store}/>));
      });
    } else {
      res.status(404).send('Not found');
    }
```

Comment: are you doing this from the server side in an universal app? Checkout their example of server rendering with 30x / 50x handling: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/ServerRendering.md

Comment: you have to provide more context if you want a working solution for your example

Comment: Well, I read their documentation. If I use <Redirect> then it works fine. But since I am redirecting programatically so I have to use context.router or any other alternative. This way doesn't trigger `redirectLocation` and therefore it provides 200 status code.

Comment: @AlexMoldovan I just updated my question by adding route match function.  I hope it will help you to better understand my problem.

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr** You need to redirect in the `onEnter` hook using the `replace` function (the second argument passed to the hook).

To understand why calling `this.context.router.replace` does not trigger a redirect, you will need to understand why a `<Redirect>` component *does* trigger one.

#### What's a `<Redirect>`?

Like `<Route>` components, a `<Redirect>` isn't a "real" component in the sense that it doesn't render anything. Instead, it just returns a route object. The route object for a `<Redirect>` includes an `onEnter` hook which calls the `replace` method of the hook, providing it the location to redirect to.

```
replace({
  pathname,
  query: route.query || location.query,
  state: route.state || location.state
})
```

#### Detecting Redirects

The way that `match` detects redirects is through `onEnter` hooks. The second argument to `onEnter` hooks is a [`replace`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3.0.0/modules/TransitionUtils.js#L56-L58) function. When that `replace` function is called, it stores the location argument as `redirectInfo`.

```
let redirectInfo
function replace(location) {
  redirectInfo = location
}
```

Now, when you call `match`, it iterates over all of your routes and determines which ones match the current location (`req.url`). It then runs any `onLeave`, `onChange`, and `onEnter` hooks (but there will only by `onEnter` hooks for the server render, so we can ignore the others here).

As the `onEnter` hooks from the matched routes are run, if at any point in time it detects that the `redirectInfo` variable has been set (by the `replace` function), it [calls the callback function](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3.0.0/modules/TransitionUtils.js#L63) which you passed to `match`, providing it the `redirectLocation`.

```
if (error || redirectInfo) {
  done(error, redirectInfo) // No need to continue.
}
```

Then, in your `match` function, you trigger a redirect using the `redirectLocation`.

```
res.redirect(redirectLocation.pathname + redirectLocation.search);
```

#### Programmatically Redirecting

So, if you want to redirect yourself, you will need to do so in the `<Route>`'s `onEnter` hook using the `replace` function. `nextState` will contain the matched routes as well as any parsed params.

```
<Route path='product/:productId' onEnter={(nextState, replace) => {
  replace(generateProductURL(nextState.params.productId));
}} />
```